# iCheck Checkbox doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, icheck

Hi have [a login site](http://gbcresearch.ca/juliet).

It works fine on browser. However, when I see it on the mobile phone, it doesn't show the checkbox.

This is the script for iCheck checkbox. It show the raw checkbox on mobile, if I remove it.

```
$(function () {
        $('input').iCheck({
            checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
            radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
            increaseArea: '20%' // optional
        });
    });
```

Could you please take a look. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There was a mistake on css file (blue.css) for retina support. the background-image link is broken.

```
background-image: url(blue.png);
```

Should be right in blue.css

```
/* Retina support */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .icheckbox_square-blue,
    .iradio_square-blue {
        background-image: url(blue.png);
        -webkit-background-size: 240px 24px;
        background-size: 240px 24px;
    }
}
```